# MSBuild doesn't create a package for a Web Service project?

Tags: web-services, msbuild, publish

We're running the following command for building and packaging Visual Studio Solutions:

```
MSBuild.exe *slnfile* /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true
```

It appears this creates packages for Web Applications but not Web Services. I don't even see a "Publish" option in Visual Studio for Web Service projects. How do I package these for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the developer didn't create a Web Application project, they created a simple empty C# project.  I converted the project to Web Application and it works.